# In EntityFramework (EF) How can I bind the ID only from a navigation property?

Tags: entity-framework

Let's take a simple example.  Suppose I had the following:

```
public class Category
{
   public int CategoryID {get;set;}
}

public class Product
{
   public int ProductID {get;set;}
   public int CategoryID {get;set;}
   public Category Category {get;set;}
}
```

EF

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasRequired(req=>req.Category).WithMany().Map(m=>m.MapKey("CategoryID"));
```

Do I have to always 'include' categories simply to get the CategoryID assigned to my product?  The SQL it generates without an .Include (e.g. db.Products.All()) will in fact return the CategoryID.

Answer (score 1):

You need .Include to populate the category nav property (otherwise it will be null). the CategoryID property will always be populated